# How to open popup automatically without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have popup which is open on

```
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px"
   onclick="ShowPopup('@Url.Action("AddEdit","PurchaseItems", new { purchaseId = Model.purchaseId ,cust = Model.customerId , org = Model.organizationId})')">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New Purchase Item</a>
```

How can I open this same thing without click automatically after page load

Comment: `ShowPopup('@Url.Action("AddEdit","PurchaseItems", new { purchaseId = Model.purchaseId ,cust = Model.customerId , org = Model.organizationId})')`

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery and Onload function
if you use sweetalart2, You can Try this out

```
<script>
Swal.fire({
    title: "<strong>Your Header</strong>",
        icon: "error",
        html: 'Text You Want to Give',
        showCloseButton: !0,
        showCancelButton: !0,
        focusConfirm: !1,
        confirmButtonText: feather.icons["key"].toSvg({
            class: "font-medium-1 mr-50"
        }) + "Button 1 Text",
        confirmButtonAriaLabel: "Forgot Your Password?",
        cancelButtonText: feather.icons["hexagon"].toSvg({
            class: "font-medium-1 mr-50"
        }) + "Button 2 Text",
        cancelButtonAriaLabel: "Try Again!",
        customClass: {
            confirmButton: "btn btn-primary mb-1",
            cancelButton: "btn btn-outline-danger ml-1 mb-1"
        },
        buttonsStyling: !1
});
 </script>
```

Dont Forget to add css and js files of SweetAlert2

Link and Examples: [Here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)